# Problem changing text content of HTML element using switch statement

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I wanted to fully understand and learn JS Switch statement so I thought of an exercise for myself - to change HTML title depending on what text of a title currently exists.

Here's the JS code:

```
var zz = document.getElementById("title").textContent;

switch(zz) {

    case "Homepage":
        console.log(document.getElementById("title").textContent);
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = "Case 1";
        console.log(document.getElementById("title").textContent + "(HAS CHANGED)")
        break;

    case "Homepage2":
        console.log(document.getElementById("title").textContent);
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = "Case 2";
        console.log(document.getElementById("title").textContent + "(HAS CHANGED)")
        break;

    default:
        console.log(document.getElementById("title").textContent);
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = "Default case";
        console.log(document.getElementById("title").textContent + "(HAS CHANGED)")
        break;
}
```

HTML:

```
<title id="title"> Homepage </title>
```

Problem is that it always executes the "default" case even though the title fits of of the presented cases. I believe the problem is within the `var zz = document.getElementById("title").textContent;` because if I declare the text content of it - it works (I don't want to do that as it just overwrites the existing title from HTML). Is it possible to achieve this with switch statement? P.S I don't want to use if/else - I want to do it with switch. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the problem is due to extra spaces around the text - for ex., ` Homepage ` instead of `Homepage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're comparing `' Homepage '` with `'Homepage'`  which is a different string because of the whitespaces.

The solution is to add trim() at the end of your first line, like so:

```
var zz = document.getElementById("title").textContent.trim();
```

[trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp): removes whitespace from both sides of a string

Answer (score 1):

```
var zz = document.getElementById("title").html().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can .innerHTML function :

```
var zz = document.getElementById("title").textContent;

switch(zz) {

    case "Homepage":
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "<title id="title"> Case 1 </title>";
        break;

    case "Homepage2":
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = "<title id="title"> Case 2  </title>";
        break;

    default:
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = "<title id="title"> Default case </title>";
        break;
}
```